# Black on black Menus in LibreOffice

Tags: windows-7

Suddenly, the menus in LibreOffice have turned black with black text. The only way to read the options is to mouse over them. Does anybody know a fix?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe you are using a dark theme on windows

Comment: I was using the dark theme and everything was fine, however, for some reason changing the theme fixed the problem. A very odd thing, something changed but I'm not sure what.
Thanks for the answer.